# In JavaScript, what code executes at runtime and what code executes at parsetime?

Tags: javascript, runtime

With objects especially, I don't understand what parts of the object run before initialization, what runs at initialization and what runs sometime after.

EDIT: It seems that parsetime is the wrong word. I guess I should have formulated the question "In the 2-pass read, what gets read the first pass and what gets read the second pass?"

Comment: It depends on your code.

Comment: When you ask about Javascript, are you specifically referring to it being used within a web browser environment?

Comment: @Spudley, I didn't know it could be used in any other environment, so yes.

Comment: there are server-side JS implementations, plus it's also built into some other apps as scripting language.

Comment: Great question, but I'll have too look elsewhere for a good answer.

Answer (score 39):

A javascript file is run in a 2-pass read. The first pass parses syntax and collects function definitions, and the second pass actually executes the code. This can be seen by noting that the following code works:

```
foo();

function foo() {
  return 5;
}
```

but the following doesn't

```
foo(); // ReferenceError: foo is not defined

foo = function() {
  return 5;
}
```

However, this isn't really useful to know, as there isn't any execution in the first pass. You can't make use of this feature to change your logic at all.

Comment: It's very useful to know, because I could easily have written the code in your second example and not understood why it didn't work.  Also, I didn't realize there was no execution during the first pass, so you're definitely clearing things up for me.

Comment: @Gareth - what about
var foo = function(){return 5;}) //undefined is not a function?

Comment: @GalMargalit No, you will get a syntax error(extra parenthesis). If you are talking about an IIFE you will get an undefined error. This is also executed on runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike C++, it is not possible to run logic in the Javascript parser.

I suspect that you're asking which code runs immediately and which code runs when you create each object instance.

The answer is that any code in a function that you call will only run when you call the function, whereas any code outside of a function will run immediately.

Comment: Is there any way to make a function in an object that runs when the object initializes?

Comment: @Randomable: What kind of object?  You can call the function in the constructor.

Comment: Okay, so you have to call it? There is no syntax of creating a function that makes it automatically run?  I think you inadvertently answered my question just then.

Comment: @SLaks You say: `The answer is that any code in a function that you call will only run when you call the function, whereas any code outside of a function will run immediately.`. Could you explain me following example(IIFE)? http://jsfiddle.net/GuyT/f81pg5hk/

Comment: @GuyT: An IIFE runs when you call it.  You just happen to be calling it immediately.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you ask exactly so I'll just share what I know.

JavaScript functions are "pre loaded" and stored in the browser's memory which means that when you have function declared in the very end of the page and code calling it in the very beginning, it will work.

Note that global variables, meaning any variable assigned outside of a function, are not preloaded, so can be used only after being declared.

**All commands outside of a function will be parsed in the order they appear.**

JavaScript doesn't really have "runtime", it can only respond to events or have code executed via global timers. Any other code will be parsed and "forgotten".

Comment: `JavaScript global variables, meaning any variable assigned outside of a function, are also preloaded and can be used by code anywhere in the page.` 

can we use it before it is initialized, the way we use parse time functions i.e `function foo() {  }`? i think no.. global variables can only be used after its initialization. this won't work `console.log(a);  var a = 20;`

Comment: @LalZada hmm... Think I checked it back when writing this, will test again soon.

Comment: @LalZada well that's embarrassing... either JS has changed, or I posted this without checking first. Edited, thanks for the heads up! :)

Comment: As you may know that Javascript is doing **hoisting** first so `console.log(a); var a = 20;` is actually equal to `var a; console.log(a); a = 20;`. Variable `a` is declared but not initialized (defined) yet before we print it using console.

Comment: @LalZada yeah, this makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

While JavaScript's direct ancestor is Scheme, JavaScript didn't inherit macros, so the answer is fairly simple: there is *never* any code run during parse time.

Comment: Don't you mean "Self", not "Scheme"? That's where it got the prototypal inheritance from. It really didn't get that much from Scheme.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly speaking, Interpreter gets all variables and functions first, and then they get *hoisted* and executed.

For more detail, I hope these links might be helpful:

- http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting
- https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/