# Javascript activity dimensions

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, i'm very new to Javascript and i'm trying to create a slideshow with Scriptaculous.

However, i can't see any way to define an area size for my Javascript element. Am i missing out on something?

I've been browsing through various sites and i'm getting zilch on any results.

If you don't understand what i'm shooting at, i'm trying to place a Javascript slideshow into my HTML page, supplied with the effects from Scriptaculous (Effect.Fade and Effect.Appear).

How am i supposed to place my javascript to run in the id="slideshow" div?

and what's the difference with

```
function functionOne() {
}
```

and

```
var functionTwo = function() {
}
```

? Which one will work best for a slideshow, and why? I've read on the net that `functionOne()` runs at parse time and `functionTwo()` runs at runtime. Whats the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normal flow for this kind of plugins would be:

you select your DOM element first like this:

```
var container =  document.getElementById('slideshow');
```

then you need to call the slideshow script passing it the element to bind to:

```
container.AwesomeSlideshow();
```

or

```
AwesomeSlideshow(container);
```

Comment: I don't really get it. This is to be written in a Javascript file, right?

Comment: Yes, you usually write it in a separate JS, which is then included in the page through an `<script type="text/javascript" src="myJS.js">/<script>`  and just call the functions inside the `document ready` event.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript works on DOM elements (like you talked about  id="slideshow" div). It doesn't have native UI elements like textarea or button (like you have in Java). If you can show which function exactly you are using for slideshow I can tell you how exactly to proceed with it.

For the second question, refer this link [In JavaScript, what code executes at runtime and what code executes at parsetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023706/in-javascript-what-code-runs-at-runtime-and-what-code-runs-at-parsetime)

Comment: i am using var functionTwo = { }, without the function() part. Am i doing this wrongly at this step? Because i'm referencing a few other Javascript documents and they all create their slideshows this way.

Comment: var FunctionTwo is not a function but just an object. var functionTwo = function () {}; will be an function.

Comment: ah......... i see. so in order for it to be displayed on screen, it must be a function?